# Mixin script added in afterrender not fired for xhr requests

Tags: tapestry

Can someone familiar with the mixin lifecycle please advise me:

(using tapestry 5.3.6)

I have a mixin which triggers some javascript from 'afterRender'. I do this in 'afterRender' because I need the field's clientId to be initialised.

It works great if the Field it attaches to is rendered when the page is first rendered, however if it is rendered as part of a zone update/xhr request, the script is never sent to the client.

I have breakpointed the JavaScriptCallback and while it is successfully added to the ajaxResponseRenderer, it is never called.

Thanks for advice!

code Eg:

```
public class MyMixin
{
    ...

    void afterRender()
    {
        addScript("MyMixin.create('%s', '%s');", field.getClientId(), myVariable);
    }

    private void addScript(final String format, final Object... args)
    {
        if (!request.isXHR())
        {
            jsSupport.addScript(InitializationPriority.NORMAL, format, args);
            return;
        }

        ajaxResponseRenderer.addCallback(new JavaScriptCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void run(JavaScriptSupport javascriptSupport)
            {
                javascriptSupport.addScript(InitializationPriority.NORMAL, format, args);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the same `jsSupport` object in both cases: `request.isXHR()` == {true or false}.

JavaScriptSupport is already registered in `AjaxResponseRenderer`, see `AjaxResponseRendererImpl`.

So your code would look like

```
void afterRender() {

    jsSupport.addScript("MyMixin.create('%s', '%s');", field.getClientId(), myVariable);
}
```

Comment: you are half right.. I no longer need to go via AjaxResponseRenderer - however it is because of the 'partialMode' now in JavascriptSupport, not because of AjaxResponseRendererImpl